# Delegate Method not getting called in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am passing some data from my ViewController to a UITableViewCell

Code in my VC :

```
protocol homeVCdelegate {
    
    func getDeviceData(_ controller : HomeViewController, deviceData : [device])
}
```

Registered the cell in my VC :

```
shortcutTable.delegate = self
shortcutTable.dataSource = self
shortcutTable.register(UINib(nibName: "shortcutCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "shortcutCell")
```

Declared Delegate in my VC :

```
var delegate : homeVCdelegate?
```

Calling delegate method inside a API Call :

```
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.allDevices = finalData2.owndevices + finalData2.deldevices
                            self.allDevices = self.allDevices.sorted(by: {$0.givenName.lowercased() < $1.givenName.lowercased()})
                            
                            self.delegate?.getDeviceData(self, deviceData: self.allDevices)
                            
                            self.shortcutTable.reloadData()
                            
                            self.sendTopicListSocket(topics: topicList)
                           }
```

Code from UITableViewCell :

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let homeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
        homeVC!.delegate = self
    }

func getDeviceData(_ controller: HomeViewController, deviceData: [device]) {
    
        self.deviceArray = deviceData
        self.deviceArray?.forEach({ device in
            self.deviceNames?.append(device.name)
            self.deviceIDs?.append(device._id)
        })
    
}
```

But the method "getDeviceData" is not getting called.

TableView implementation in HomeVC :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = shortcutTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shortcutCell", for: indexPath) as! shortcutCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.deviceArray = self.allDevices
    
    return cell
}
```

UITableView cell Swift File :

```
class shortcutCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    var deviceArray : Array<device>?
```

CollectionView cell inside the UITableView cell file : Print statement returns nil.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        print("DEVICE ARRAY COUNT", self.deviceArray?.count as Any)
 
        return self.deviceArray?.count ?? 1
    }
```

didSelectItemAt method for CollectionViewCell inside the UITableViewCell : This works fine that means deviceArray is not nil at this moment and deviceArray has received data from HomeVC

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print(self.deviceArray)
        print(indexPath.row)
        print(self.deviceArray?[indexPath.row].givenName)
    }
```

Comment: I have also added protocol homeVCdelegate to cell class

Comment: You shouldn't declare `homeVC` in `awakeFromNib`. It will create multiple view controllers unnecessarily. The cell should use to represent data only. So, move your `homeVC` to view controller which holds the tableView, declare `deviceArray` in this view controller, request API, set it to the array then fill to cell.

Comment: You create `homeVC` in `awakeFromNib` and then throw it away immediately. What do you expect?

Comment: What does your table view data source implementation look like? Especially relevant are `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` and `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`.

Comment: You should think why you need to call homeVC from table view cell. Is it for initialisation or does it happens when the cell is on screen ? If the cell needs to call some other VC its delegate should be set when you set the cell contents in cellForRow.

Comment: What I am doing is that I am now passing deviceArray directly in HomeVC (removed the protocol - delegate). I have edited original question with more details. Now inside the cell is a collection view, so basically it is a single row of scrollable collection view cells. When you click the collection view cell, it is supposed to print deviceArray elements, which is working. But in the 'numberOfItemsInSection' inside the TableView swift file which returns the number of collection view cells, the deviceArray shows nil. Code in the question above.

Comment: @AbheshekSharma - very confusing... you say *"`numberOfItemsInSection` prints `nil`"* ... but you also say *"`didSelectItemAt` works fine"*? How do you have any items to select if `self.deviceArray?.count` is nil?

Comment: Because I am returning an integer value if the self.deviceArray?.count is nil. Here :return self.deviceArray?.count ?? 1

Comment: @AbheshekSharma - ok, so you return `1` if you have no data in `numberOfItemsInSection` ... what do you get in `cellForItemAt` for that one item? As you were told, you shouldn't be creating `homeVC` in `awakeFromNib` ... did you fix that? You commented that you *"... edited original question with more details ..."*? You should edit your question again, and post the actual code you are using. Best option would be to put together a [mre].